# Phonegap Auth Cookie Access for Login After App Closed

Tags: cordova, session, cookies

I have created a sessions database table that stores a session key, the client side app checks if key exists and is valid and logs them in and adds the session key to a cookie.

Once the app is loaded in the simulator it allows the user to login however once the app is closed and re-opened it fires an ajax call but doesn't remember the cookie auth key and doesn't log the user in again.

Any ideas on using cookies with Phonegap? Or should I be using Phonegap's HTML5 local storage API to store the username and password?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can use html5 local storage

```
localStorage.setItem('usernameKey', username);
```

where usernameKey is the key and username is the value

And when you check to get the item 
use

```
localStorage.getItem('usernameKey');
```

Also make sure to set the expiration date

```
expires.setFullYear(expires.getFullYear() + 100);
```

Edit: This is how you do it

```
var username = "something"; // your username value 
var password = "some password"; // your password value
localStorage.setItem('usernameKey', username);
localStorage.setItem('passwordKey', password);
expires.setFullYear(expires.getFullYear() + 10);
document.cookie = escape(username) + "=" + escape(password) + "; expires ="+ expires.toGMTString();
```

and to get cookie like I mentioned before you use this

```
localStorage.getItem('usernameKey');
localStorage.getItem('passwordKey');
```

Hope this was helpful :)

Comment: This is perfect, thank you.

Can the expires.setFullYear be added in the setItem like this:?

localStorage.setItem('usernameKey', username, expires.setFullYear(expires.getFullYear() + 100));

Comment: Great, so how many days is expires.getFullYear() + 100 equal too? Preferably just want it to be 30 days, if this is possible?